# Navbar transparent in buefy

Tags: vue.js, buefy

I am creating a landpaging and I am facing some style difficulties due to lack of practice.

I want to modify the backgroud of the navbar, so I wanted to make the background transparent so that the bottom of the page appears. How can I do this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3KKR.png)

```
<template>

<div class="Shellhub-LP-1280">
  <div class="textura Nuvem">

    <b-navbar>

      <template slot="brand">
          <b-navbar-item tag="router-link" :to="{ path: '/' }" transparent="true">
              <img
                  src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/buefy/buefy/dev/static/img/buefy-logo.png"
                  alt="Lightweight UI components for Vue.js based on Bulma"
              >
              <!-- <img src="@/static/logo-inverted.png"> -->
          </b-navbar-item>
      </template>

      ...

    </b-navbar>
  </div>
</div>

</template>

<style>

.Shellhub-LP-1280 {
   /* width: 100%; */
   height: 2283px;
   background-color: #333640;
}

.textura {
   /* width: 100%; */
   height: 771px;
}

.Nuvem {
   width: 100%;
   height: 755px;
   object-fit: contain;
   opacity: 0.9;
   float: right;
   background: url('../static/nuvem.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: right;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**buefy navbar API:**

https://buefy.org/documentation/navbar/#api-view

Passing this props:

```
<b-navbar :fixed-top="true"  :transparent="true" >
```

**Vue docs - components props** (recommend to read):

- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

---

### transparent "bug":

Open **github** issue:
[BUG: navbar is-transparent not working](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/1395) .

**IMPORTANT**: `transparent` affect `navbar items` (Not the navbar wrapper himself).

> Remove any hover or active background from the navbar items

So add simple CSS styling:

```
nav.navbar.is-fixed-top {
  background: transparent;
}
```

### body top padding issue

I won't find a way to remove body top padding. I added this style:

```
body{
  padding-top: 0px!important;
}
```

### Basic example:

```js
const app = new Vue()
app.$mount('#app')
```

```css
img.responsive_img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
body{
  padding-top: 0px!important;
}

/* change navbar background color */
nav.navbar.is-fixed-top {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/buefy/dist/buefy.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="app">
    <b-navbar class="is-link" :fixed-top="true"  :transparent="true">
        <template slot="brand">
            <b-navbar-item tag="router-link" :to="{ path: '/' }">
                <img
src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/buefy/buefy/dev/static/img/buefy-logo.png"
alt="Lightweight UI components for Vue.js based on Bulma"
                >
            </b-navbar-item>
        </template>
        <template slot="start">
            <b-navbar-item  href="#">
                Home
            </b-navbar-item>
            <b-navbar-item href="#">
                Documentation
            </b-navbar-item>
            <b-navbar-dropdown label="Info">
                <b-navbar-item href="#">
About
                </b-navbar-item>
                <b-navbar-item href="#">
Contact
                </b-navbar-item>
            </b-navbar-dropdown>
        </template>

        <template slot="end">
            <b-navbar-item tag="div">
                <div class="buttons">
<a class="button is-primary">
    <strong>Sign up</strong>
</a>
<a class="button is-light">
    Log in
</a>
                </div>
            </b-navbar-item>
        </template>
    </b-navbar>

    <header style="min-height: 200vh;">
      <img class="responsive_img" src="https://picsum.photos/2000/600"/> 
  </header>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/buefy/dist/buefy.min.js"></script>
```

## Change navbar background color on scroll

`only by custom code`

See this codepen (I added a class on scroll):
https://codepen.io/ezra_siton/pen/jOPZgmR

**Change the background color on scroll her:**

```
nav.navbar.is-fixed-top.isActive{
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
  background: red; /* change color on scroll */
}
```

**Change navbar links color to white (For dark hero) - add "is-link" modifier:**
https://bulma.io/documentation/components/navbar/#colors

```
 <b-navbar  class="is-link" :fixed-top="true"  :transparent="true" >
```

**Remove hover/active**

`:transparent="true"`
Remove any hover or active background from the navbar items.

Comment: Very thanks your attention. But I have other question, I want color the nav bar when I use the scroll. Do you know the propriedade?

Comment: And I remove the background white when I put the mouse on itens.

Comment: I edit the answer --> +1 if this solves your issues (Or mark as a solution).

Comment: Please +1 (Or comment +1) on github for this idea: https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/2871